# difficulty getting PHP server to work on MacBook Pro

Tags: php

Brand new to php and trying to run php server on my MacBook Pro without installing anything.

Despite following the general convention and watching some videos online in order to configure such, I cannot get the project to load on the localhost which is confusing. I keep getting NOT Found error / The requested resource/ was not found

Here is my process.

1. The project folder is imported into sublime my text editor.
2. In terminal I `cd` into the folder (`ls` confirms its existence).
3. I start the sever using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080`(I get a response to say its listening on that port).
4. But then when I go into localhost:8080 (nothing but the error).

Does php need a 3rd party server or is there a problem in how I am trying to go about this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Customer</title>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$Fname = "";
$Sname = "";
$Full = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $Fname = $_POST["firstname"];
   $Sname = $_POST["surname"];

   $Full = "Your Full Name is " . $Fname . " " . $Sname;
}

?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <br><br>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="surname">
   <br><br>
       <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
       <br><br>
   <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"> 
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Details are :</h2>";
echo $Fname;
echo "<br>";
echo $Sname;
echo "<br>";
echo $Full;
echo "<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In terminal I cd into the file (ls confirms its existence).

That's impossible. It should give you this error:

> ```
> cd: not a directory: test.php
> ```

You need to cd into the directory containing the PHP file.

---

> But then when I go into localhost:8080 (nothing but the error).

If you aren't going to specify the filename in the URL, you need to name it `index.php`.

It will 404 Not Found if you call it something else.

Comment: I have cd into the directory,